# Using Animated Switcher, which are stored in a List

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to have a Scaffold, which contains a variable amount of Elements in a ListView. The Elements are all equal, just a few values are different. So I made a Scaffold for those Elements and want to store them in a growable List. My Problem is, that the AnimatedSwitcher doesn't work anymore when I retrieve it from the List.

[image: The upper code shows the children of the ListView in form of a List. If I run this code the AnimatedSwitcher doesn't work. It just shows the first child without switching to the second. The lower code shows the children of the ListView without storing the AnimatedSwitcher in a List first. If I run this code the AnimatedSwitcher is working.]

```dart
bool Boolean = false; <br/>
List<Widget> widgets = [ AnimatedSwitcher(<br/>duration: Duration(seconds: 2), <br/>child: Boolean ? childrenOne : childrenTwo) ]

body: ListView( <br/>
children: widgets
),
```

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: I think my code is a chaos, you wouldnt understand it, but I was able to specify the problem. I will add an image, which shows it.